# What is an m-ary vector?

Tags: vector, arity

I am watching a lecture on threading and they use the term `m-ary vector` as follows:

```
"Let [X] represent an m-ary vector of non-negative integers"
```

What is this? Is the arity the length? I presume a vector is merely a sequential data structure like an array? Why would the letter `m` be used - I have only ever seen `n-ary` previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the arity the length?

Yes.

> I presume a vector is merely a sequential data structure like an array?

Yes.

> Why would the letter m be used - I have only ever seen n-ary previously.

There are twenty-six latin letters that could be used.  If -- later -- they are going to talk about two different length vectors, they're going to need to different letters.